# Send image from one activity to another from a list view

Tags: android, android-intent, bitmap, android-imageview

I have a list view which displays a image, name, price.

What m trying to do is on click on that list I should send the image the name and price to next activity.

```
Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DescActivity.class);
ImageView img=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.list_image);
String name=((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name)).getText().toString();
String price=((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.price)).getText().toString();
Bitmap bitmap = img.getDrawingCache();
in.putExtra("IMAGE", bitmap);
in.putExtra("NAME",name );
in.putExtra("PRICE", price);
startActivity(in);
```

But the above code is not working. please help me. m stuck with this for 3 days :'(

Comment: what is not working any crash if so pste your logcat

Comment: The image not getting loaded in the next activity

Comment: @user1743673 mention next activity code here how you are accessing bitmap

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this,

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
Bitmap b = img.getDrawingCache();
ByteArrayOutputStream bs = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 50, bs);
i.putExtra("myImage", bs.toByteArray());
startActivity(i);
```

Then in your next Activity use

```
if(getIntent().hasExtra("myImage")) {
    ImageView image = new ImageView(this);
    Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(
        getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("myImage"),0,getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("myImage").length);        
    image.setImageBitmap(b);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this-
make bitmap static in first activity. i.e.

```
static Bitmap bitmap = img.getDrawingCache();
```

and in second activity-

```
 Bitmap _mBitmap=FirstAcitivity.bitmap;
```

Comment: note that static variables are kept in memory, so careful if you decide for this way.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use this-
in first activity-

```
   Drawable drbl=_imageView.getDrawable();
   Bitmap bit = ((BitmapDrawable)drbl).getBitmap();
   intent.putExtra("Bitmap",bit);
```

In second acivity-

```
 Bitmap _mBitmap=intent.getParcelableExtra("Bitmap");
 Drawable _mDrawable=new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),_mBitmap);
```